# Firebase Job Dispatches doesnt trigger my service class

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm using Firebase Job Dispatcher to schedule service, but this don't trigger my Service class.

I need help to implement this service.

minSdkVersion 16

targetSdkVersion 25

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("SCHEDULER", "onCreate()");

        // Create a new dispatcher using the Google Play driver.
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10, 20))
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
                .setTag("location-update-job")
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .build();

        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);

    }
}
```

MyJobSerivce.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;

public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
        Log.d("SCHEDULER", "onStartJob()");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        Log.d("SCHEDULER", "onStopJob()");
        return false;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alugalogo.igor.jobdispatcher">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".MyJobService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I only get "onCreate()" log result.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: For which device on which Android version is this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Try add to your job builder:

```
.setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
// constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
```

Comment: Why would that even be necessary at all?

Answer (score 1):

Once a job with a tag is created, new job with the same tag will be rejected by default. To recreate the job with the same tag one should use `.setReplaceCurrent(true)` method on a JobBuilder instance.

So you can try to use this method to recreate the job with desired start time.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes:

1. Return `false` in `onStartJob`

   that means: all work is done! 
   javadoc:

   ```
   @return {@code true} if there is more work remaining in the worker thread, {@code false} if the
    * job was completed.
   ```
2. Return `false` in `onStopJob`

   that means: all work is done, don't reschedule! 
   javadoc: `@return true if the job should be retried`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to add to manifest BIND_JOB_SERVICE you only have ACTION_EXECUTE:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```